# Change link in contents listing for custom content type

Tags: plone

I have created a custom content type, based on the existing 'Image' type. 
When I look at the contents tab of a parent folder, actual images have a link like this:

> .../arumsans/arumsans.png/view

Where my type has a link like this:

> .../arumsans/bold

And when clicked shows only the image in the browser.

How can I modify the way these links are made so that my type has

> .../arumsans/bold/view

or

> .../arumsans/bold/edit

Comment: What's the star in the URL? I am not sure if I understood why you want to have a star there...

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: those are attempts at highlighting the part he wants to add to the URL. :-)

Comment: I was trying to italicise the words. It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to list your type in the `typesUseViewActionInListings` property of the `site_properties` property sheet in the `portal_properties` tool.

To do this manually, navigate to the ZMI, find the tool and click on it, then click on the `site_properties` sheet, then find the `typesUseViewActionInListings` entry and add the `portal_type` of your custom type in that list.

To automate this, add a `propertiestool.xml` file to the GenericSetup profile of your package that defines the type, and make sure it contains the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_properties" meta_type="Plone Properties Tool">
 <object name="site_properties" meta_type="Plone Property Sheet">
  <property name="typesUseViewActionInListings" type="lines">
   <element value="YourCustomPortalType"/>
  </proyerty>
 </object>
</object>
```

(with your `portal_type` value filled in) and re-import the profile.